# Filtering an object based on its values using lodash

Tags: javascript

How would I use lodash to get the following output ?

```
input = {
'property1' : true,
'property2' : false,
'property3' : false
}
// only pick those properties that have a false value
output = ['property2', 'property3'];
```

I currently have the following in place:

```
var output = [];
_.forEach(input, (value, key) => {
  if (value === false) {
   output.push(key);  
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Plain JS you can do:

```
var output = Object.keys(input).filter(function(k) { return input[k] === false })
```

Comment: Something similar using lodash: `_.filter(_.keys(input), key => !input[key]);`

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that using `lodash`:

```
const output = _.keys(_.pickBy(input, function(value, key) {return !value }));
```